# How do I Use audioread to read a sequence of files and then combine them?

Tags: matlab, audio

I am am trying to read all wav files within a folder and then combine those files. I understand audioread and audiowrite. I am struggling to automate the processing of a sequence of files within a folder so that I only have to change the dirin name and can move to the next folder. The code here obviously doesn't work but trying to demonstrate what I want to do.

```
DirIn = 'C:\Users\24hr sound analysis\17';

eval(['filelist=dir(''' DirIn '/*.wav'')']);

for i = 1:length(filelist);
[f(i),fs] = audioread(strcat(DirIn,'/',filelist(i).name)); % read in wav file
end

combined = [f1;f(i)]; 

audiowrite('combined.wav',combined, fs)
```

EDIT: I implmented suggestio below as follows but now have a new issue. I combined 6 1-minute wav files and my output is 6mins and 36 seconds. Where is that extra 26 seconds coming from?

```
DirIn = 'C:\Users\24hr sound analysis\17';

eval(['filelist=dir(''' DirIn '/*.wav'')']);

cd(DirIn);

combined = [];

fs = 44800

for i = 1:length(filelist);
        Filename = filelist(i).name;
        aud_file = audioread(Filename);
        combined = [combined;aud_file];
end

audiowrite('combined.wav', combined, fs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do the following and insert the `audioread` function in it:

```
dir_name = 'full path to the main folder';
sub_dir_names = dir(fullfile(dir_name,'*'));
N = setdiff({sub_dir_names([sub_dir_names.isdir]).name},{'.','..'}); % list of only subfolders of D.
combined = [];
for ii = 1:numel(N)
    T = dir(fullfile(dir_name,N{ii},'*')); % improve by specifying the file extension.
    C = {T(~[T.isdir]).name}; % files in subfolder.
    for jj = 1:numel(C)
        F = fullfile(dir_name,N{ii},C{jj})
        % do whatever with file F.
        % simple implementation assuming all the files are .wav
        aud_file = audioread(F);
        combined = [combined;aud_file];
    end
end
audiowrite(combined, Fs);
```

While you in the inner loop concatenate the files you read using the `audioread`.

When you go outside of the looping just write the file with `audiowrite`; it should perform the task your after.

**Note**

This is just for showing you the logic of how to traverse all subdirectories inside a directory, there is of course more ways to do what you desire.

Comment: The issue for me is that I don't know how to do this with audioread in particular. I have other code (cobbled together) in which I loop throigh folders and perform tasks within the loop (e.g., sort files based on file name). In this case, I just don't know how to read and then write in way that is repeatable when a directory may have between 1-6 wav files to combine.

Comment: @brc the inner loop goes through all the files in the subdirectory so if there is *k* `.wav` files in it you can read them one after the other, combine them and then write back; I dont understand what is the problem exactly

Comment: @brc you can read the following like to how concatenate wav files: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/479800-how-can-i-combine-multiple-wav-files-into-a-single-new-wav-file; its support my above comment

Comment: I am very very new at Matlab and coding. What is basic to you is advanced for me. I just don't know how to do what you suggest, read them, combine, and write.

Comment: those answers were not helpful for me. The code suggested by Walter requires me to ID each file but I have thousands of files in hundreds of folders. Ideally I could just change the DirIn and move to the next folder.

Comment: @brc I dont follow you, in my code every file name `F` in each iteration will be a `.wav` file. you then use the `audioread` function -> use an array to store them all and concatenate them vertically (for array `d` and the output of `audioread` lets say `a` you do `d=[d;a]` and so on). when the reading is done just write `d` using `audiowrite`; **This is really straight forward approach**

Comment: I literally don't understand what "store them all and concatenate them vertically" means. Like I said, what is easy for you is not so easy for me.

Comment: @brc I wrote it in the brackets in the comment above: *for array `d` and the output of `audioread` lets say `a` you do `d=[d;a]` and so on*

Comment: Would you mind showing how that would work in my code? I think where I'm confused is that I don't understand all of the functions in your code. What I'm trying to do is pretty simple in that I don't mind specifying the specific folder to look at.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201219/discussion-between-brc-and-david-s).